# pymysql update not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymysql

I need to do an Update so I made this, but I got a problem with this code.

```
def runUpdate(query, aux):

#Establecemos la conexion con la base de datos
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='root', db='influencers', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        #Ejecutar query
        cursor.execute(query, aux)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        #Guardar cambios conexion
        connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

It seems ok, but when I made this:

```
runUpdate("""UPDATE Influencers SET tweets = '%s' WHERE usuario = '%s'""", (numTweets, user))
```

It throws me an error here:

```
cursor.execute(query, aux)
```

This is some of the console text:

  `(...)
    return escape_str(value, mapping)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 71, in escape_str
    return "'%s'" % escape_string(value, mapping)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 68, in escape_string
    lambda match: ESCAPE_MAP.get(match.group(0)), value),))
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

I think my syntax is wrong, but I don't see why. I'm learning to code at Python, so please be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please print your numTweets and user , check them is string or not.

If your para numTweets and user is a list type, you should use

```
cursor.executemany(operation, seq_of_params)
```

check the document https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Comment: Wow, so fast. It was helpful, both your code and also the link. It works perfect now. numTweets was a dict, btw. Thx!